# How to use colors in java spring dropdownlist

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown list in my spring form.I need to fill options of that dropdown list with different colors.I am now getting string directly as #00FF00.Browser not converting it to corresponding color.I need green color at there for my code at there.I tried to make background color as same and hide the letters.But i am iterating using model attribute and i am not able to give colors for all dropdownlist.

Below is my code in my controller

```
@ModelAttribute("color")
public Map<String, String> colors()
{   
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("green","#00FF00");
    map.put("blue", "#0000FF"); 
    return map;
}
```

my jsp page

```
<form:select path="colorCode" class="monthanddates"> 
                      <form:option value="" label="select" />                               
                     <form:options items="${color}" class="color " />
                                </form:select>
```

I need to map the values of corresponding color code to database(using spring tags).So that i am using controller to implement it.Can anyone help me any help will be highly appreciable.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsp page you can use JSTL as below:

```
<form:select path="colorCode" class="monthanddates" cssStyle="background: ${colorCode}"  onChange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor">
                <form:option value="" style="background:#FFFFFF" label="select" />
                <c:forEach items="${color}" var="colorMap">
                    <option value="${colorMap.value}" style="background: ${colorMap.value};"></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
```

Make sure you have this on your jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: but the selected color doesnot depends on parent tab

Comment: parent tab?! can you explain more?

Comment: parent tab is parent button of dropdown which gets clicked to view the items(list) ie our select button.In my requirement i need to fill it with the selected color

Comment: Do you want the value of text appear or only the color?

Comment: only the color appear at there

Comment: What value do you want to submit as colorCode green or #00FF00 for example?

Comment: #00FF00 is the value i need to submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89144/discussion-between-guissouma-issam-and-vishnu-m).